What is the phalasruti and reference of the given Saraswati mantras?
What is the source of this mantra? What are the phalasruti of this mantra mentions in the prescribed text?
Om Arham Mukha Kamal Vaasinee
Paapaatma Kshayam Kaari
Vad Vad Vaagwaadinee Saraswati
Aing Hreeng Namah Swaaha ||
And
Vad Vad Vaagwaadinee swaha.
